# How can I change the template that Android Studio uses to create a blank activity

Tags: templates, android-studio

I would like to change the template so that the new activity uses `AppCompatActivity` instead of the depreciated `ActionBarActivity`

I found `sdk\tools\templates\activities\BlankActivity\root\src\app_package\SimpleActivity.java.ftl` and after making a backup copy I changed

```
import <#if appCompat>android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity<#else>android.app.Activity</#if>;
```

to

```
import <#if appCompat>import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity<#else>android.app.Activity</#if>;
```

and

```
public class ${activityClass} extends ${(appCompat)?string('ActionBar','')}Activity {
```

to

```
public class ${activityClass} extends ${(appCompat)?string('AppCompat','')}Activity {
```

but when I create a new activity it still uses ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just change two position:

1.import <#if appCompat>android.support.v7.app.**AppCompatActivity**<#else>android.app.Activity;

2.public class ${activityClass} extends ${(appCompat)?string('**AppCompat**','')}Activity {

And it's work for me!

I see you code, your first edit has one more "import" string.  -_-|||

**Edit:**
By the way,  I edit `SimpleActivity.java.ftl` under **Android-Studio folder**:`"X:\xxxx\android-studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\activities\BlankActivity\root\src\app_package"`

Comment: I use Intellij, not Android Studio. I change this file but it doesn't have any effect, I still get the old template when I create a new `BlankActivity`. Any idea why?

Comment: Anyone know if it's possible to have project-specific templates? I.e., not have to modify templates inside the application directory. I've been searching around and haven't found anything about project specific templates yet.... :-(

Comment: @stuckj You can use Code Templates, in Preferences->Editor->File and Code Templates, just add some  templates. Then right click on project folder area, select New, and you can find the templates you have just add.

Comment: I'm not at my computer now, but I thought those templates are different. I thought those were velocity templates for creating single files. The ones that setup multiple files for all the Android cases are freemarker templates. I'm specifically trying to use them to make multiple files for an MVP pattern for Android activities. Not sure if you can do that with the velocity templates.