# Edit the template Visual Studio uses to create an API Controller

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, api, templates

Using VS 2017, in an API project, you can create a new Controller.  If you select `Web API 2 with Read/Write Actions`  it will ask you for a name, and if you call it `UsersController`

It will give you a template that looks like this:

```
    // GET: api/Users
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Users/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST: api/Users
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT: api/Users/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/Users/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
```

If I wanted to edit this template, would that be possible? And if so, how?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468484/change-default-mstest-unit-test-wizard-template) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256841/how-can-i-change-the-template-that-android-studio-uses-to-create-a-blank-activit) didn't get me very far.